Translating 'Amenability' in the Context of Locally Compact Groups
I am working on my thesis on the composition of operators, and since I am writing it in Greek, I would like to translate the word 'Amenability.' I would appreciate some help in understanding this property of locally compact groups so that I can find a Greek word that represents it.
